# Google Script: How to run UiApp from the SpreadSheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I created Google Script Ui App, which runs fine in standalone mode. But I need to run it from the Spreadsheet and not sure how to do that.we

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this line of code at the end of the `doGet()` function to replace the `return app`

```
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
```

btw, note that you don't need to call it `doGet` anymore, you can use any name you want in this context.